# Apache file index on /files, Reverse proxy on /

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a Python/CherryPy program running on port 7000. It handles it's own webserver, so I've used an Apache reverse proxy so that I can access it with mydomain.org. This works; the config is below.

I would also like Apache to serve (with Index) any files in directory /media by accessing mydomain.org/files. The purpose being to plug a USB drive into the server, it automatically gets mounted on /media/usb and I can give someone the link.

```
<Location />
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Secure"
     AuthBasicProvider file
     AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/auth
     Require valid-user
     Allow from 192.168.1.1/24
     Satisfy Any
     ProxyPass http://localhost:7000/
     ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:7000/
</Location>
```

I'm new to Apache so could easily be confused or haven't given enough information or haven't found the right search terms. If so, please let me know .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the directory `/media` does have a correct configuration
(you need `mod_autoindex` module to be loaded)

```
<Directory /media>
    Allow from all
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Set the alias to point to `/media`

```
Alias /files /media
```

Make sure to not proxy the `/files` URL space by using ! in the directive

```
ProxyPass /files !
```

The complete configuration for a particular virtual host can be following

```
<Directory /media>
    Allow from all
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>

Alias /files /media

<Location />
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Secure"
     AuthBasicProvider file
     AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/auth
     Require valid-user
     Allow from 192.168.1.1/24
     Satisfy Any
</Location>

ProxyPass /files !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:7000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:7000/
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more? My guess is that under `<Location />` you are _not_ proxying `/files` (is that what `!` means?) and then allowing access to `/media`, but where are you linking `mydomain.org/files` to `/media`?

Comment: I've edited the answer. Yes, exclamation mark makes the URL space to be excluded from proxying. And yes, I've forgot to make a required alias. Was somehow assuming that the document root will be set to "/media" which is an option.

Comment: Okay thank you! However, I don't think `ProxyPass /files !` should be in a Location block: it causes error: `ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch can not have a path when defined in a location.`

Comment: Furthermore, I have to put `ProxyPass /files !
<Directory /media>
    Allow from all
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>
Alias /files /media` **before** the code I have in my question.  Can you please add that to your answer (if correct?). Thank you for the help.

Comment: Oh yes, right normally you have it outside location and I guess the "ProxyPass http://localhost:7000/" works, because normally outside of location block you would say "ProxyPass / http://localhost:7000/". You may want to do it so you have ProxyPass directives on one place.

Comment: Perfect. Future people: the accepted answer is correct, my comments could be misleading/bad practice.